# Elastic Search measure heap usage

Tags: elasticsearch

How I can use heap usage of elastic search cluster between some time range? I want to check performance and heap usage of elastic search if I am continuously updating documents and at the same time doing full-text search operation.
So How we can check heap usage if both operations running simultaneously in a specific time period?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own Elasticsearch [plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.5/index.html) that uses Java [JMX APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) to get the current usage of memory before/during/after the search operation.

But don't trust very much this information because the garbage collector can kick in at any time and your reports may be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch exposes APIs which you can query to check heap usage, among other things. 
There is a utility already out there which sends such metrics from elasticsearch to graphite. Take a look.

https://github.com/logzio/logzio-es2graphite